# How does (else) if and || work and which is better?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how these 2 block of codes executes,they have different outputs, do I have to use else if on the first block, if so, which is faster?

[demo](https://repl.it/CcbL)

```js
var output = 0;
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {

  if (n % 3 === 0) {
    output += n;
  }
  if (n % 5 === 0) {
    output += n;
  }
}
console.log(output);

/* ------------------------- */

var sum = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 3 === 0 || x % 5 === 0) {
    sum += x;
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: First one executes this statement `output += n; ` twice if a number is divisible by both 3 and 5. Second one doesn't. Which one do you need?

Comment: they will work the same if you add the else

Comment: @gurvinder I am thinking of which is more efficient, else if or || ?

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio 99% of the time you don't need to micro-optimise.

Comment: If this is for Fizz Buzz test, the first approach will be more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `else if` instead of the second `if` in the first block, you should get the same results.
For example, `n=15`:

- in the first block of code:

  1. you check `n%3 === 0` is true, so `output` is increased by 15
  2. you check `n%5 === 0` is true, so `output` is increased by 15 again
- in the second block of code:

  1. you check `n%3 === 0` is true, no other checks are done, `sum` is increased by 15
- if you use `else if`:

  1. you check `n%3 === 0` is true, so `output` is increased by 15
  2. no other checks are done

I believe `||` and `else if` speeds are pretty the same. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code, for the numbers divisible by 15(lowest common multiple of 3 and 5), sum was getting added twice.

In the second block of code, as its a || statement. Only once sum was added if its a multiple of 15.

Check the third block of code, I added. I am just looking for the sum of the multiples of 15. See its the exact diff you were finding.

```js
var output = 0;
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {

  if (n % 3 === 0) {
    output += n;
  }
  if (n % 5 === 0) {
    output += n;
  }
}
console.log(output);

/* ------------------------- */

var sum = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 3 === 0 || x % 5 === 0) {
    sum += x;
  }
}
console.log(sum);
/* ------------------------- */
sum = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 15 === 0) {
    sum += x;
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```